# Strange bug with double deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

```
    An error occurred while deserializing the ruleArgs field
     of class Test.Test.Common.TesterObject: Cannot deserialize a 'Double[]' from BsonType 'Double'.
```

I got this error when my .NET app tries to deserialize the following class from Mongo

```cs
public class TesterObject
{
    public Type ruleType;
    public string ruleDesc;
    public double[] ruleArgs;
}
```

Now I get the error no matter if `ruleArgs` is a `double[]` or `int[]` or `string`. This error is fixed if I either delete that field all-together or rename it from `ruleArgs` to `ruleParam`

Anyone knows if `ruleArgs` is some kind of special name reserved for something in Mongo? I couldn't find anything about this name.

Comment: The wording is exactly the same for all of the errors?

Comment: yes even when i change the type, the strangest part is just it completely goes away if i simply change the field name, even tho that name is never used in any of the hierarchies of any class being serialized into mongo

Comment: Please only use the "JavaScript/CSS/HTML" code snippet feature *for JavaScript/CSS/HTML* - not for error messages which are just text, or for C# code.

Answer (score 1):

The error says exactly what's wrong, your document contains a double value but you want to convert it into array of doubles

Comment: but the error is fixed if i simply change the field name, also i get the same error regardless if change the type to string, double or array of doubles as long as the field name is the same

Comment: `if change the type to string, double or array of doubles as long as the field name is the same ` - I doubt it's true statement. `but the error is fixed if i simply change the field name` - and newly named fields has expected values? Anyway you should provide a full code you use in that case